# Issue in updating a sql server `varbinary` column using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

When I code an insert, everything works great. For example:

```
dataCommand.CommandText = "use mydb; INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(@binaryvalue);
dataCommand.Parameters.Add("@binaryvalue", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 256).Value = mycard;
dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

However, if I try to update, it won't work. I used the .WRITE method, but it won't do:

```
dataCommand.CommandText = "use mydb; update mytable set mycolumn .Write(@binaryvalue, 0, NULL) where myid = " + wid;
dataCommand.Parameters.Add("@binaryvalue", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 256).Value = mycard;
dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

How can I perform an update instead of deleting/inserting?

Thanks for any response!

Comment: Stop using the `use mydb;` inside your SQL script - by means of the connection string, you're **already** defining what databas you're running in....

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the problem is the `NULL`:

```
.WRITE (expression,@Offset,@Length)         (reference)
.Write(@binaryvalue, 0, NULL)               (your code)
```

Try putting the length of your content instead of `NULL`.

> @Length is the length of the section in the column, starting from @Offset, that is replaced by expression. @Length is bigint and cannot be a negative number. **If @Length is NULL, the update operation removes all data from @Offset to the end of the column_name value.**

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx

Comment: I changed the length, and still get the same error message: "Cannot call methods on varbinary." According to MSDN, my syntax is perfect, and MSDN says you need to use ".WRITE" for varbinary updating, so I don't understand why it won't work! Any other ideas?

Comment: I was assuming you just typed in your example code incorrectly, but your `update... where myId=...` looks at the identity, but in your example insert doesn't specify the id.  Do you have a primary key on the table?

Answer (score 0):

What's the exact type of the binary column in the table? Is it VARBINARY(MAX)? If not please try it and see if it works.
According to the documentation:

> "Use the .WRITE (expression, @Offset, @Length) clause to perform a partial or full update of varchar(max), nvarchar(max), and varbinary(max) data types"

and

> "To achieve the same functionality of .WRITE with other character or binary data types, use the STUFF (Transact-SQL)."